# Display LaTeX-Quotation marks as unicode characters

Tags: latex, auctex, font-lock, unicode

When quoting in auctex, I use the strings `` "` `` and `"'` to typeset `„` and `“`, respectively. Now, I want emacs to display the corresponding unicode characters to these strings. I've tried it with `prettify-symbols` but as it seems it can only handle *single characters*, not strings of characters. So my question is: How can you display `` "` `` in emacs as `„` and `"'` as `“`?

Comment: I use prettify-symbols to display multi-character strings into single symbols, this should work

Comment: Does that mean your question is answered? If so, you probably should take your edit and make it into an answer (yes, you can answer your own question). Then, after the required waiting period (I believe it's 48 hours but I could be wrong), you will be able to accept your answer. That will allow future visitors to know that the question has been answered to your satisfaction, something which is not obvious in the current state.

Comment: @NickD Yes it does, thanks for the info. I'm new to this site. I just did it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Tyler's comment, I now know that **it is possible to assign a single character to a string of characters with `prettify-symbols`**! I simply forgot to put a question mark in front of the unicode symbol. For anyone as lost as me, here is the code:

```
    (setq TeX-symbols-list '(lambda ()
    (mapc (lambda (pair) (push pair prettify-symbols-alist))
        '(
      ("\"\`" . ?„)
      ("\"\'" . ?“) 
                   ))))
```

Additionally, you can tell LaTeX to print `` "` `` and `"'` if you press `"` at the beginning or end of a quote, respectively:

```
(setq TeX-open-quote "\"`")
(setq TeX-close-quote "\"'")
```

This way, you can use quotation marks the same way you would use them in Word.